# Error : unfortunately, ePlay3Service has stopped

Tags: android, bluetooth, iot, android-things, android-anr-dialog

[image]I have developed an android app, which connects to the Arduino via Bluetooth and receives data continuously. Everything was working fine two days ago but now sometime, my android device has been showing a pop-up message like **unfortunately, ePlay3Service has stopped** It doesn't affect my app but it shows up after some time.

Device Configuration:

- Device Name : Swipe Slice tab
- Android OS Version : 4.4.2

If you need any further information, please comment below.

P.S. **ePlay3Service** is not my app name. I have searched for it but still, I haven't got any clue for that.

Comment: Its hard to be accurate without device logs/package details, but **ePlay3Service** seems to be a part of 3rd party package installed in your device.

Comment: I have doubt about it though I have used this "pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.+" library in the project. Is that library create that problem?